# Selenium Webdriver - Refresh Stale Element Shortcut?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a Selenium test for my Rails application, and sometimes run into the "Stale Element" exception. It's easy enough to perform another lookup on the element before operating on it, but to keep my code DRY, I'm wondering - is there any sort of method available on `Selenium::WebDriver::Element` objects to "refresh" stale references?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm asking if there's some shorthand method for doing another `find_by_xpath` (or `id`, etc.) call with the same parameter being passed. It's perfectly functional, just not as terse as some sort of "refresh" method would probably be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking about some sort of "refresh" or "update" method on a `WebElement` instance.

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in `selenium` by definition. According to the relevant issue [WebElement refresh() or getBy() needed](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4419):

> WebElement object is a proxy, a representative of a DOM element. When
>   DOM element is destroyed by the browser, WebElement is marked "stale"
>   and can't be used anymore.
>
> If you have a *similar* DOM element on another page, you can obtain it
>   with findElement, and Selenium will create a *new* WebElement object
>   (a proxy) for this *new* DOM element. Your old WebElement object will
>   remain stale because underlaying DOM object is destroyed and never can
>   be restored. Similarity is not equality.

I would recommend store element-specific locators, but once the page refreshes, you would still need to "refind" the element by the locator.

Comment: Basically, yes. I can just do another `.find_by_xpath()` call to refresh the element, but a "refresh" method seems more terse. Not a big issue, just wondering. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing available is keeping track of your application state when writing your Selenium code.

Did you perform an action that refreshed the DOM? Then you need to perform another `findElement` call to get a new instance of the element you want to interact with next.

Otherwise, write your own method `findElementByXpath` in a Utility class that tries to find an element, catches a StaleElement exception and retries.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to describe my case which is similar:
I tried to find a table cell with some value by doing this:

1. Get all table rows
2. For each row - get a collection of the columns
3. For each column - seek the value

One day, I had a case with too many results in the table. So, I programmed the loop to click the "Get next page" link/icon.
Simple? no! when the program clicked the "next page of the table" link, the WebElement which pointed to the table was not usable, I received the same error as the author of this question:  StaleElementReferenceException

What I did is:

Get the XPATH of the table first, and then I changed the loop so if all the rows were scanned, and  he value was not found and if the next icon is enabled:

1. Click the next page of the table.
2. Update the WebElement to re-point the table.

I hope I am clear.